# jQuery TinySort weird behaviour with sorting li by value

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-lists

I've tried to sort list li elements by attr "value"

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li value="3" title="broken" style="display: inline;">
        <button class="cloudbutton">broken(3)</button> </li>
    <li value="4" title="aggressive" style="display: inline;">
        <button class="cloudbutton">aggressive(4)</button> </li>
    <li value="0" title="agonizing" style="display: inline;">
        <button class="cloudbutton">agonizing(0)</button> </li>
    <li value="1" title="bad" style="display: inline;">
        <button class="cloudbutton">bad(1)</button> </li>
    <li value="2" title="beaten" style="display: inline;">
        <button class="cloudbutton">beaten(2)</button> </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("ul>li").tsort({attr:"value"});
```

seems to be a problem with tiny sort

Here's my example (use latest jQuery 1.8.2):

    http://jsfiddle.net/W2dQH/6/ - TinySort 1.0.1 (yeah.. sorts as ordered)

    http://jsfiddle.net/W2dQH/5/ - TinySort 1.4.29 (doesn't sort at all)

it looks like both version doesn't finish work correctly.

Yes, i can workaround this by writing my custom sorting function, or sort by something else, but this case is rather basic and I don't know what's going on..
So, what's wrong with it?

**Edit**

useVal doesn't work too

```
$("ul>li").tsort({useVal:true});
```

but sorting by title is fine..

```
$("ul>li").tsort({attr:'title'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah that's a real bug, it tries to match a regexp on an int and fails. I'll let you know when it's fixed.